# focusOutEvent is not called

Tags: c++, qt

I included `#include <QFocusEvent>` into my code and implemented `focusOutEvent` as follows:

```
void MyWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
   if(e->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "hello");
   }

}
```

Widget descriptor has the following extra lines:

```
  installEventFilter(this);
  setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
```

I also have definition on header file as follows:

```
virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent * event);
```

The problem is, whatever I do (tab or clicking somewhere else) did not call this focus event. How can I solve this?

Comment: `installEventFilter(this);` should be removed. Generally there is no need to add an event filter object for the same object. Also it can be the cause of the trouble if the event is filtered in `eventFilter` method implementation (if any).

Comment: Removed `installEventFilter`, but no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did the trick for me was to force the focus on the dialog.
i.e.:

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog();
...
dialog->show();
dialog->raise();     // to make sure it's shown on top
dialog->setFocus();
```

Originally I had a `dialog->activateWindow()` that's supposed to set the focus to the dialog just the same, but `setFocus()` seems to get the job better done.

Then my re-implemented `focusOutEvent()` got called when I clicked anywhere outside the dialog.

***Note:*** This was tested on Fedora 25 (KDE Spin) with Qt 5.7.1

Answer (score 3):

may be it wasn't called because it didn't match to declarion in QWidget

```
virtual **protected** void QWidget::focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )
```

also you cant try to call `setMouseTracking(true)`(documentaion says no need in this but may be this can help) and it will be good to call a original event handler
could you specify os you are running ?

Comment: I will try and let you know. I am using openSuse

Answer (score 0):

check if `MyWidget` is displayed in **modal** way(modal: you can't interact with parent widget).

if so, then `MyWidget` is always in focus when its parent is in focus(I guess).

what you can do is not to display it in **modal** way(call `show()` instead of `exec()` )

or you can make it a top-level widget(no parent).